# windows 2008, Resize partition

Tags: windows, vhd, disk-utility

I try to split my hard drive to 3 partition by Windows tools, I have 385 GB free space on C drive but when I try to shrink it , only it allows 25 GB to be shrinked.
windows report it is for unmoveable data on defrage alanyse.
How can I split my partition or defrage the hard ?

also I try to use VHD instead of split hard drive but every time I restard windows I have to attach again VHDs, Can I use vhd as an alternative for regular partition?

best wishes
Mehdi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the third party partitioning tool, Acronis or Paragon software have some good ones.

http://www.acronis.com/homecomputing/products/diskdirector/

Paragon is cheaper
http://www.paragon-software.com/home/pm-personal/eshop.html

.

and here is a Free one.

http://www.partition-tool.com/personal.htm

Note: be sure to back up important data before changing partitions, also make the rescue CD/DVD if the software has that feature (most do).

.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that the free EASEUS partition tool you mentioned will not work on Windows Server.

Comment: The boot disc you can create will. You may have to install the program on another Windows PC and make the boot disc though.

Answer (score 1):

You can use also free opensource GParted. It can work with NTFS partitions also.

http://sourceforge.net/projects/gparted/files/gparted-live-stable/