# "Extend volume" is not working in Windows Vista

Tags: windows-vista, logical-drive

I am using Windows Vista Home Premium Service Pack 2. I have now 4 volumes "C:", "D:", "E:", "F:". Now I shrink 30 GB space from my "C:" drive. I want to extend any of the "D:" or "E:" drive with the free space. But when I am right clicking on any of these volumes, "Extend volume" option is disabled. How can I extend this volume?
Some Screenshots are given below:

**Screenshot 1:**
[image]

**Screenshot 2:**
[image]

**Screenshot 3:**
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't extend backwards on the drive, only forwards. That space will only be available to your `C:` drive.

To manage your partitions more effectively, check out this question:

[windows 2008, Resize partition](https://superuser.com/questions/159661/windows-2008-resize-partition/161109)

Comment: What is "backwards" and "forwards" here. I don't know. Can you please explain?

Comment: Look at the picture. Left is backwards, right is forwards. You cannot resize the drive on the right using the space freed up on the left. You can only resize with space available *immediately* to the right of the given drive.

Comment: Are there any procedure to extend "backwards"?

Comment: Check my updated answer.