# How can I extend a partition to unallocated space on the left?

Tags: windows-8, partitioning, disk-management

I want to extend the partition C: (without losing its contents) by adding the extra free (Unallocated) space before it. However as you can see, the extend is disabled. I know that extend will be enabled when the extra space is *after* the main partition, the reverse of this situation.

[image]

How can I achieve this?

Comment: There's no such thing as "extending to the left" in this case.  You're looking to **move** the partition and then to extend it.  You're also looking to move the **boot** volume.

Comment: Related: [Extending hard disk partition backwards without third-party tools](http://superuser.com/q/346089/78897).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Extend Windows 7 partition to use free space before it](http://superuser.com/questions/134994/extend-windows-7-partition-to-use-free-space-before-it)

Answer (score 2):

Extending the next partition to the left is, as I think, impossible with Windows Disk Management.

So you would need to use software like GParted to do that.
Booting from USB stick or CD/DVD would be needed.

Please run

```
chkdsk /f c:
```

before booting [GParted](http://gparted.org/).

Comment: Last time I did that with GParted it messed up my partition. Couldn't boot anymore.

Comment: Use a newest stable GParted always.

Answer (score 0):

yes it's possible and I found the solution without losing anything;

an application called [AOMEI Partition Assistant](http://www.extend-partition.com/download.html) can do this;

the exact same situation is described here: [Windows - Adding Unallocated Drive Space "From the left"](http://www.petenetlive.com/KB/Article/0000678.htm)

Comment: As this can fulfil your requirements, GParted is, as many people can say, better trustworthy than other software of this kind (not only because it is open source).

Comment: tnx anyway for your clarification