# I want to increase the size of home partition in Ubuntu 23.04

Tags: ubuntu, hard-drive, partitioning, disk-space

I have installed ubuntu with windows in dual boot and I have about 100gb in free space which is not partitioned anywhere but I cant seem to find any solution that fits my problem. I have about 150 gbs of free storage that i want to add to my home directory so that I can have much more stuff on here.
[Softwares and Storage are two partitions which have data.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jGBAO.png)
[image: Softwares and Storage are two partitions which have data.]

[image: This is list of block devices(lsblk)]

Please Note that ubuntu is installed on hard drive and not the nvme.

Answer (score 1):

First, before making *any* change to the file system **make a full disk image and verify it.** This not only lets you recover from mistakes, but can be used to restore data to a changed partition.

From that image, it appears that there is about 100 GB free space immediately before a Linux *ext4* partition of ~80 GB. Trying to extend the 80 GB partition *backwards*, **down** into that space, is difficult, though *theoretically* possible. Easier is to [delete the 80 GB partition, and then combine them](https://superuser.com/questions/346089/how-to-extend-hard-disk-partition-backwards-to-the-left-without-third-party-to/346186) into one 180 GB partition. Here are two ways you might do this:

1. Delete *all* six partitions, starting *after* the NTFS, and combine them into one block of ~200 GB free space.

   Now completely reinstall Ubuntu, letting it use that 200 GB block of free space. You might be able to restore the data in the old 80 GB partition to replace the new Ubuntu installation. Since Ubuntu can work with a swap *file*, rather than a swap *partition*, that would also free up a bit more space.
2. Delete the 80 GB Ubuntu partition (effectively destroying Ubuntu, again), and combine that with the 100 GB free space.

   Create a single 180 GB partition.

   Format it *ext4*.

   Now restore the data from the 80 GB partition into that new 180 GB partition.

As for the 52 GB of free space after "Softwares Partition 1", ~450 GB, the safest way to use it would be to extend Partition 1 up into that free space.